# How to prove these two functions are always equal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $/$ stands for **integer division**, we have these two functions:

$$f(a,b) = (a + b - 1) / b$$

and

$$g(a,b) =
\begin{cases}
a/b,  & \text{if $a \mod b = 0$} \\[2ex]
a / b + 1, & \text{if $a \mod b \neq 0$}
\end{cases}
$$

We can see $f(a,b)$ equals to $g(a,b)$ by filling a and b with actual numbers, but how do you prove that they are always equal? I've answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44867340/4357087) but I think I was over-complicating it so not really convinced by myself.

This problem is quite common in real life. Consider we have 10 students and now we need to divide them into several groups each of which has the same number of students, say, that number is 3. Now we need to calculate how many groups there will be, and the answer is 4. If we put it into math function then $g(a,b)$ is a natural way of thinking, but $f(a,b)$ also does the job. Why?

Comment: Since this site is for asking math questions, could you rewrite your expressions using MathJax so that we have some formulas to look at?

Comment: Exactly @James...

Comment: Thus, a % b == 0 means that a is a mult of b ?

Comment: @James Since this problem concerns both math and programming and I doubt if there's a way to express the second in a math formula I think it's proper to show them in code format.

Comment: And a / b + 1 is $\dfrac a b +1$ or $\dfrac {a}{b+1}$ ?

Comment: Let's try ... Let's set $b=2$ and $a=1$ (integers). Then $\frac{a+b-1}{b} = \frac{2}{2}= 1$ but $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{2} = 0$ (integer division) ... so it seems weird ...

Comment: Maybe the "+1" at the end of r2 is added in any case. I would recommend using parentheses to make the expression unique.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The same as the rule of precedence in algebra, i.e. the first one.

Comment: @MattiP. Yep, the fraction line can't really be used to express integer division. So it's better to show them as code.

Comment: Matt P the OP didn't introduce the ternery ?: operator. It acts as an if (lhs of ?) then (middle) else (rhs of :)

Comment: If a % b == 0 means $a=kb$ for $k$ positive integer, then we have that r1 is $(k+1)b-1=kb$ which is not true in general.

Comment: @MattiP. It's the same as the rule of precedence in algebra so for simplicity I omitted that.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sometimes the distributive law doesn't apply to integer division. For example, if a = 4 and b = 2, then r1 = 2 and r2 = 2, so r1 = r2. But if r1 = (k + 1)b - 1 = 5, it's not the same as the original.

Comment: @IvanHuang $$f(a,b)=\begin{cases}\frac{a}{b}, & a\mod b =0\\ \frac{a}{b}+1,& a\mod b \neq 0.\end{cases}$$ and $g(a,b)=\frac{a+b-1}{b}$. You see it is definitely possible to write them in a more math-usual form.

Comment: @IvanHuang Is there probably a typo in your question? Because if I take any $a,b$ such that $a\mod b\neq 0$, then $f(a,b)=\frac{a}{b}+1$ whilst $g(a,b)=\frac{a+b-1}{b}=\frac{a}{b}+1-\frac{1}{b}$ so both functions differ by  $-\frac{1}{b}$. Moreover, for $a\mod b=0$ they differ by $1-\frac{1}{b}$.

Comment: @James Keep in mind it's **integer division**, so $g(a,b)=\frac{a+b−1}{b}\neq\frac{a}{b}+1−\frac{1}{b}$. You can fill the variables with some numbers to test, for example, a = 4 and b = 2.

Comment: @IvanHuang I see. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89666/discussion-between-ivan-huang-and-james).

Answer (score 1):

For positive integers $a$, $b$, the two expressions are the same.

Suppose $a=qb+r$, where $q=a/b$ (quotient) and $r=a\%b$ (remainder). Then $$a+b-1=(q+1)b+(r-1)$$ If $r\ge1$ then $r-1$ is the new remainder and the new quotient is $$(a+b-1)/b = q+1 = a/b + 1$$ Otherwise if $r=0$, then $a+b-1=qb + (b-1)$, which gives the second formula $$(a+b-1)/b = q = a/b$$

Comment: In the second step how are you sure $(a+b-1)/b = q+1$ and $(a+b-1)\mod b = r - 1$? Why can't it be, say $(a+b-1)/b = q-1$ and $(a+b-1)\mod b = r+b-1$? The same goes with the third step, how do you make sure the new quotient is $q$ and remainder is $b-1$? I couldn't really follow that.

Comment: @Ivan Huang. By the definition of remainder, $r<b$, so $r-1<b$ for the second step; and obviously $b-1<b$ for the third. Note that quotients and remainders are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try a=-1 and b=2 and you may be surprised.

Different languages define operators differently. Integer division may round to negative infinity or to zero. The % operator in most languages is not the modulo for negative numbers.

Comment: Okay... then I'll add that a and b are both positive integers...

Answer (score 0):

Notice that we can express integer division in terms of vanilla-flavoured division using the *floor* function. For example, your function $f$ could be expressed

$$f(a,b)=\left\lfloor\frac{a+b-1}{b}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{a-1}{b}+1\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{a-1}{b}\right\rfloor+1$$

and $g$ could be expressed

$$g(a,b)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle\left\lfloor\frac a b\right\rfloor,&\left(\exists k\in \mathbb Z\right)\left(a=kb\right)\\
\displaystyle\left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor+1,&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.$$

Before we see why $f$ and $g$ are equivalent it might help to notice the following:

- If $a$ can be expressed as $kb+r$ where $k\ge 0$ and $0\le r<b$ then $$\left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{kb+r}{b}\right\rfloor=k+\left\lfloor\frac r b\right\rfloor=k$$
- We can "complete the remainder" to get the identity:$$\left\lfloor\frac a b\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{kb+r\color{darkorange}{+(b-r)}}{b}\right\rfloor-1=k$$

(For example, if $a=28$ and $b=5$ so that $k=5$ and $r=3$. Notice that $\left\lfloor\frac {28} 5\right\rfloor=5$ and that $\left\lfloor\frac {28\color{darkorange}{+2}} 5\right\rfloor-1=5$.)

Now, if we consider the cases in $g$ separately:

Case 1: $a$ is a multiple of $b$

$$\begin{align}
\left\lfloor\frac{a-1}{b}\right\rfloor+1
&=\left(\left\lfloor\frac{a-1\color{darkorange}{+1}}{b}\right\rfloor-1\right)+1\\\\
&=\left\lfloor\frac a b\right\rfloor
\end{align}$$

Case 2: otherwise

In this case there exist unique $k\ge 0$ and $0<r<b$ such that $a=kb+r$, so

$$\begin{align}
\left\lfloor\frac{a-1}{b}\right\rfloor+1
&=\left(\left\lfloor\frac{kb+r-1+\color{darkorange}{(b-r + 1)}}{b}\right\rfloor-1\right)+1\\\\
&=\left\lfloor \frac{b(k+1)}{b}\right\rfloor\\\\
&=\left\lfloor k+1\right\rfloor\\\\
&=\left\lfloor\frac ab\right\rfloor+1
\end{align}$$